# How to prove there exists a unique $H$ such that $A=H-H^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How to prove there exists a unique $H$ such that $A=H-H^{-1}$? Here, $A,H$ are both positive-definite $n\times n$ real matrix.

Clearly, existence is easy by diagonalization. What about uniqueness?

Comment: This question is seemingly related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691294

Comment: Presumably, you mean to ask something like "**given a positive definite matrix $A$**, why does there exist a unique **positive definite** $H$ such that $A = H-H^{-1}$?"

Comment: Yes, this is a weird way to phrase this question. Start with the givens - here $A$ - then tell us what you want to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\phi(z)=z-{1 \over z}$ defined on $\operatorname{re} z >0$ is analytic with an analytic inverse
$\eta(w) = {1 \over 2} (w+\sqrt{w^2+2^2})$.

Suppose $H=U \Lambda U^*$, then $A=\phi(H) = U \phi(\Lambda) U^*$ and $\eta(A) = U \Lambda U^* = H$.

In particular, if $A = \phi(H_1) = \phi(H_2)$ then $H_1 = H_2$.